# Unable to get RegularExpressionValidator to work

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

Working with C# atm, and want to use RegularExpressionValidator on the password.
I want the following to be required when typing the password:

- Minimum 6 characters
- Minimum 2 numbers
- No limit in the number of letters allowed

---

- test12
- t1es2t
- 12test
- tt123est
- t111test

are exemples of passwords that should be allowed.

I have tried with som combos, but for now I got this:

```
(([aA-zZ]*)([0-9]{2}){6,}
```

But thats not working...

Comment: I would just count up each type of character rather than using a regular expression

Comment: Yeah, but I need to use the regular expression. It's a part of the task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is difficult to combine all your requirements into one regex. The trick here is to use a positive lookahead assertion to check for the overall length.

```
(?=^.{6,})(?i)[a-z\d]*?\d[a-z\d]*?\d[a-z\d]*
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?384l1)

`(?=^.{6,})` [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), checks that the string has a length of at least 6 chars.

`(?i)` [inline modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), makes letter matching case independent.

`[a-z\d]*?\d[a-z\d]*?\d[a-z\d]*` letters or a digit, A digit required, letters or a digit, A digit required, more possible letters or digits.

Comment: Thank you so much! Understood a bit more, but will read so I can understand it 100%. Again, thank you.